# How do I uninstall postgres on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, mac, postgresql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I uninstall postgres on Mac OS? Can’t kill data](https://superuser.com/questions/170827/how-do-i-uninstall-postgres-on-mac-os-cant-kill-data)

I'd like to uninstall postgres on Mac OS 10.6 and start again with a completely fresh installation and empty databases.

I am in some confusion at present, with multiple installs - I had a macports install and also an install from the [KyngChaos binaries](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/postgres) on the same machine, which caused problems.

I've been following the 'Manual Uninstallation' [steps on this page](http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/list/2159.page). The only existing postgres that I know about is in `/usr/local/pgsql`, so I substituted that filepath in step 5. I've tried `locate pg_config` to see if there are any other installs floating around, and I can't see any. (although possibly that's the wrong command to use?)

However, when I reinstall with the KyngChaos binaries, I can still log into postgres as 'postgres' with my old login, and I can still see all my old databases, and data.

Where is this data coming from? Is it possible there's still another install on my machine, and if so, how can I found out where it is, and kill it?

Answer (score 1):

`lsof | grep pg` and/or `lsof |grep ostgre` and see if you can locate what data files are still in use by whatever postgresql process is running.